# How to save messages from Gmail to csv file?

Tags: gmail, csv, export

I want to know how to save messages from Gmail to one csv file or each message to separate csv file. Txt file is also acceptable. The messages I need have a certain label in Gmail.

An example:

I have 50 messages marked with label "Notification" and I want to export all of them to one csv file Notifications.csv

Comment: A list of the messages or the actual content of the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking how to do this via GMAIL only is off topic (See [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)), I'll answer how to do it in an email client. In this case, Outlook. I've kept this quite open in order for it to apply to older versions of Outlook.

Add a new account in Outlook - download them all via POP3. Make sure you don't delete them from the server (there is a option for that).

Create a new folder in Outlook.

Perform a search in Outlook for the string you want to search for. Drag all of these into the new folder.

Export to a file, then choose CSV. From here, select this new folder.